# Making a folder black and white with python

Tags: python, image, scikit-image, scikits

I have a folder of JPEGs. They are all RGB. I want to convert them all to greyscale with scikit-image.

```
import glob
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage import img_as_uint
import os
from PIL import Image


list = os.chdir("C:/Users/Images/RGB")
for file in list:
    image1 = Image.open(file)
    image_converted = color.rgb2gray(image1)
    io.imsave("C:/Users/Images/Greyscale", image_converted)
```

I get the error message :

```
    AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

What am I doing wrongly here ?

Comment: `os.chdir()` doesn't return you a list of files, it just changes directory. After that, you need `list=glob.glob('*.jpg')`

Comment: When you save the result, you need `os.path.join()` to join the filename to the directory name.

Answer (score 2):

Give this code a try:

```
from skimage import io, color
import os
import imghdr

source = r'C:\Users\Images\RGB'
destination = r'C:\Users\Images\Greyscale'

image_files = [os.path.join(root, filename) 
                   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source) 
                   for filename in files 
                   if imghdr.what(os.path.join(root, filename))]

for fn in image_files:
    rgb = io.imread(fn)
    grey = color.rgb2gray(rgb)
    head, tail = os.path.split(fn)
    io.imsave(os.path.join(destination, tail), grey)
```

Notice that `image_files` is a list containing the full path name of all the image files found in `source` and its subdirectories (recursively). The complete list of image types being detected can be found at the documentation of the [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not running the script in the directory the files are located.

Either use the full file path for `Image.open(file)` or `os.chdir` into `"C:/Users/Images/RGB"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my first issue. I've updated my question. Any idea what might solve this issue ?